# Nested Loop in table PHP

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-table

I am new to PHP and I am trying to make a table using two foreach and I am not getting the output I want.

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Didier Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Yesso!</h1>
    </body>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Books</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    <tr>

    <?php foreach($name as $item): ?>
        <td><?=$item?></td>
        <?php foreach($price as $item2): ?>
            <td><?=$item2?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

I know I am having an issue with my inner foreach, but I don't know how to correct it.

Please let me know.

Comment: Which issue? What's going wrong?

Comment: Your loop might not work because there is no data in your variables. Please use `var_dump($name, $price)` and show us the result. These must be arrays for the loops to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing you are closing your body tag on line 7, before you even output your table.

```
<body>
<h1>Yesso!</h1>
</body>
```

I also don't know why you are doing a nested loop on seemingly non-related data. Other than that we would need to see your query.

Comment: Maybe all items have the same prices, for whatever dimension the columns are. But I suspect Zak's answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

Since you start the row with `<tr>` before the first loop, you need to end the row with `</tr>` after it:

```
<tr>
<?php foreach($name as $item): ?>
<td><?=$item?></td>
    <?php foreach($price as $item2): ?>
<td><?=$item2?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
for($i = 0; $i< count($name); $i++) {
    $item  =  $name[$i];
    $item2 =  $price[$i];

?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$item?></td>
    <td><?=$item2?></td>
</tr>

<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your shorthand php output notation `<?=` with full `<?php echo`

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Didier Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Yesso!</h1>
</body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Books</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php foreach($name as $item): ?>
    <td><?php echo $item?></td>
    <?php foreach($price as $item2): ?>
    <td><?php echo $item2?></td>
</tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You probably dont get any output because your php.ini has set not to allow shorthand php '

Oh, and yes, like mentioned by Barmer and Revent, you have some HTML tag-nesting issues as well. Welcome to the wonderful world of PHP & Good luck :)