# PHP nesting foreach in table

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I can't seem to get my table to have the right output. The code is the following:

```
<div class="bubbleTitle">Spetsialistide tööaeg graafiku alusel</div>
    <table style="width: 600px" class="slicedTable">

        <tr>
        <th>Spetsialist</th>
        <th>Tunnid</th>
    </tr>

<tr>            
    <?php foreach($specs as $specName => $spec): ?>
    <td><?php echo $specName?></td>
            <?php foreach($tunnid as $tund): ?>

    <td><?php echo $tund?></td>
</tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have tried everything in this thread: [Nested Loop in table PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114945/nested-loop-in-table-php)  , but none of that has worked either
The output is the following:

name - value

value2

value3

 name2 - value

value2

value3

etc.

I would like it to be:

name1 - value1

 name 2 - value2  etc.

Where  `$tunnid` comes from:

```
result = mysql_query("SELECT `worker_id`, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `start`, `end`)) as `total` FROM
    `spa_worker_times` WHERE (`start` BETWEEN '".$validated['start']."' AND '".$validated['end']."') AND
    (`end` BETWEEN '".$validated['start']."' AND '".$validated['end']."') GROUP BY `worker_id`") or die(mysql_error()); 


$tunnid = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $tunnid[] = $row['total'];
```

Where specs come from:

```
$data = $this->BookingProcedures->query("SELECT AProcedure.name, BookingGroup.booking_package_id > 0 AS pack_proc," .
                        "SUM(BookingProcedure.price) AS price, Worker.name, COUNT(BookingProcedure.id) AS num" .
                    " FROM spa_booking_procedure_specialists BookingProcedureSpecialist, " .
                        "spa_booking_procedures BookingProcedure, " .
                        "spa_booking_groups BookingGroup, spa_procedures AProcedure, spa_workers Worker" .
                    " WHERE !BookingProcedure.deleted" .
                        " AND DATE(BookingProcedure.start) >= '".$validated['start']."'" .
                        " AND DATE(BookingProcedure.start) <= '".$validated['end']."'" .
                        " AND BookingProcedureSpecialist.booking_procedure_id = BookingProcedure.id" .
                        " AND Worker.id = BookingProcedureSpecialist.specialist_id" .
                        " AND BookingGroup.id = BookingProcedure.group_id" .
                        " AND AProcedure.id = BookingGroup.procedure_id" .
                    " GROUP BY AProcedure.name, BookingGroup.booking_package_id > 0, Worker.name");
```

Comment: How do you want it to be displayed? Show an example of your desired output

Comment: How do you want to display the data when you have multiple values for a name? All answers are based on guesswork now...

Comment: There can't be multiple values for a name, each name is paired with a value, the mysql command should take of that

Comment: then there is no use of putting a foreach inside the table, con you show use the mysql-query for specs and tunnid?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bubbleTitle">Spetsialistide tööaeg graafiku alusel</div>
<table style="width: 600px" class="slicedTable">
     <tr>
      <th>Spetsialist</th>
      <th>Tunnid</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>            
       <?php foreach($specs as $specName => $spec): ?>
        <td><h2><?php echo $specName?></h2>
        <table><tr>
        <?php foreach($tunnid as $tund): ?>
           <td><?php echo $tund?></td>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
       </tr></table></td>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

This will output like this

```
Name1
value1 | value2 | value3
Name2
value1 | value2 | value3
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention what I wanted, but I edited it in earlier, I woul like to have a regular table with each row containing name1 - value1 and the next name2 - value2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($specs as $specName => $spec) { ?> 
  <tr>            
    <td><?php echo $specName?></td>
    <?php foreach($tunnid as $tund) { ?>
      <td><?php echo $tund?></td>
    <?php } ?>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

will result in

name value value value
name value
name value value
and so on

Where does $tunnid come from. I would assume it contains only values, but in which way, are they in a regular array or an associative? My code would work if $tunnid contains the values to one name. But i assume that is not the case!?

Comment: The mysql command that creates $tunnid, calculates a value for each name separately using a worker id. I just need each name to have it's value next to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($specs as $specName => $spec){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $specName?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tunid[$i++]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="width: 600px" class="slicedTable">
     <tr>
      <th>Spetsialist</th>
      <th>Tunnid</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>            
       <?php foreach($specs as $specName => $spec): ?>
        <td><?php echo $specName?></td>
    <!-- seperate with anything -->
    <td><?php echo implode(',', $tunnid); ?></td>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
     </tr>
 </table>
```